# Installing Gazebo on a mac (Lion OSX)

Tags: gazebo, macos, macos-lion, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Have anyone installed Gazebo in an iMac?**

I am trying to install it in Lion (mas OSX). I have downloaded the source code, tar it, use make, and then got stuck trying to use cmake.

The problem seem to be that I don't have these packages: build-essential libtinyxml-dev libtbb-dev libxml2-dev libqt4-dev pkg-config  libprotoc-dev libfreeimage-dev libprotobuf-dev protobuf-compiler libboost-all-dev freeglut3-dev

I have tried to get them with Flink and apt-get, but it just won't find the packages. **Is it possible that, since I am using Lion, there are no suitable versions of those packages and thus apt does not find them?**

Thanks a lot for your comments. I have been searching the web for hours and I cannot figure out the way of finishing the installation of Gazebo. I have also searched this forum, but I got no results for "mac" or "OSX", so I guessed this is the first time this question is being asked.
Also, I am starting a new project and lots of these things are new to me, so please tell me if I am doing something wrong. Thanks again.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12769/installing-gazebo-on-a-mac-(lion-osx)/) by [jabellcu](https://answers.ros.org/users/1698/jabellcu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-01-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Gazebo, currently has not been tested on OS X.

The new version of Gazebo (to be release in Fuerte) should support OS X, but the current one probably will not work, there are several problems preventing it from running on OS X.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2012-02-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Those package names are all for debian (most likely ubuntu) You'll have to find what the equivalent package name is for the package manager you're using. Alternatively (although I don't recommend it) you could go out and fetch and manually compile all of those dependencies yourself.

That said, I can not comment on whether gazebo is able to run/compile on OS X after you have all the dependencies.

---

Originally posted by [John Hoare](https://answers.ros.org/users/159/john-hoare/) with karma: 765 on 2012-01-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2